# How can I convert Datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, Date) / 7 * 7) / 7 + 1 AS WeekNumOverall to U-sql

Tags: sql, u-sql

I want week number in u-sql and want to convert below code into u-sql

```
Datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, Date) / 7 * 7) / 7 + 1 AS WeekNumOverall,
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Would it be better to have a pre-calculated date dimension where you simply looked this up?  Import one from your favourite data warehouse.

Answer (score 4):

Within U-SQL you can use .NET DateTime properties and methods. Instead of DATEPART you can use DateTime.DayOfYear (see [DateTime Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)). Something like:

```
SELECT Date.DayOfYear / 7 + 1 AS WeekNumOverall FROM 
(VALUES (new DateTime(2017,1,1)) , (new DateTime(2017,3,1)) , (new DateTime(2017,10,12))) AS vt(Date);
```